# Node-webkit not working on Linux(CentOS)

Tags: packaging, node-webkit

I am trying to build on Linux machine then its response is

Lib64/LibC.so.6: version GLIB2.14 not found.
Lib64/LibC.so.6: version GLIB2.15 not found.

Comment: Does the message really have weird capitalization and GLIBC misspelled?

Answer (score 1):

Your distribution version is too old and is no longer supported by node-webkit. See a [similar issue](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/1366) reported on the node-webkit bugtracker.